# How to make interactive footer in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, components

I want to build a Interactive footer. I don't want to load an other page with new footer. I only want to change footer Component it self by click on links.

```
<footer className="Footer">
        
                   <Link to="/">
                   <img className="Footer__logo" src={logo} alt="logo"/>
                   </Link>
        
                   <div className="Footer__Nav">
                  
                   <Link className="Footer__link" to="/email">
                   <AlternateEmailIcon />
                       <span>Email</span>
                   </Link>
                   <Link className="Footer__link" to="/development">
                   <PhoneIcon />
                       <span>Telefon</span>
                   </Link>
                 
                   </div> 
                   
</footer>
```

Comment: Create a footer component and alter accordingly.

Comment: i have a footer component and inside only logo email and phone number. i want to click email and load email footer on the same page. but i was thinking maybe an other footer router i need ?

Comment: Okay so what do you want do with that? Please edit and elaborate the question

Comment: i just put my footer component like i try to say is i dont want to render new page i just want to render new footer in actual page.i dont want to build an other contact or email page.i only want is if i click email on footer footer must be stay same there but load a different content with email infos